# Own params to PeriodicTask run() method in Celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am writing a small Django application and I should be able to create
for each model object its periodical task which will be executed with
a certain interval. I'm use for this a Celery application, but i can't understand one thing:

```
class ProcessQueryTask(PeriodicTask):
   run_every = timedelta(minutes=1)

   def run(self, query_task_pk, **kwargs):
       logging.info('Process celery task for QueryTask %d' %
query_task_pk)
       task = QueryTask.objects.get(pk=query_task_pk)
       task.exec_task()
       return True
```

Then i'm do following:

```
>>> from tasks.tasks import ProcessQueryTask
>>> result1 = ProcessQueryTask.delay(query_task_pk=1)
>>> result2 = ProcessQueryTask.delay(query_task_pk=2)
```

First call is success, but other periodical calls returning the error
- TypeError: run() takes exactly 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given) in
celeryd server.
Can I pass own params to PeriodicTask `run()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was answered wonderfully by Ask Solem in [his response to your question](https://groups.google.com/group/celery-users/browse_thread/thread/233f3adead54ec3f/78588a5ab1778887#78588a5ab1778887) on the [celery-users Google group](https://groups.google.com/group/celery-users).

Periodic tasks doesn't use arguments, so you need to make several
classes or make a periodic task that processes more than one "model".

E.g.:

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

# base class
class BaseProcessQueryTask(PeriodicTask):
    abstract = True
    run_every = timedelta(minutes=1)
    query_task_pk  = None

    def run(self):
        task = QueryTask.objects.get(pk=self.query_task_pk)
        task.exec_task()

class ProcessQueryTask1(BaseProcessQueryTask):
    query_task_pk = 1

class ProcessQueryTask2(BaseProcessQueryTask):
    query_task_pk = 2
```

but it's more likely you want something like this:

```
@task(ignore_result=True)
def execute_query_task(task):
    task.exec_task()

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=1))
def process_query_tasks():
    for task in QueryTask.objects.all():
        ExecuteQueryTask.delay(task)
```